# C Program Pauses After Reading First Input

Tags: c, buffer, newline, flush

I'm working on a C program intended to remove blank lines between text from a .txt file. The program asks the user for the names of the source and destination files. However, I'm encountering an issue where the program seems to pause or hang after receiving the name of the source file. It only continues on to asking forr the destination file name AFTER the user hits enter a second time. I've tried using scanf and fgets, and also attempted to flush the stdin buffer, but the problem persists. I'm using the exact code for grabbing file names as my last 3-4 labs so I am clueless on what is wrong. The program ends when it gets to the first fopen. The if statment at this point runs and is True..  so the source file name is somehow being misinterpreted.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main() {
    FILE *source, *destination;
    char source_file_name[256], destination_file_name[] = "output.txt", buffer[1024];

    // Prompts user for file name to search, reads the name into our buffer, and stores the file name. Will also clear the buffer.
    printf("Enter the source file name: "); 
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    sscanf(buffer, "%s", source_file_name);

    // Prompts user for file name to use for the copy.
    printf("\nWhat would you like to name the duplicate file? (default name: output.txt): ");
    fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), stdin);
    if(strlen(buffer) > 1) { // If a name is entered, it is used. If not, the default is used.
        sscanf(buffer, "%s", destination_file_name);
    }
    source = fopen(source_file_name, "r");
    if(!source) {
        perror("The source file was not found.");
        return 1;
    }

    destination = fopen(destination_file_name, "w");
    if(!destination) 
    {
        perror("Could not create the destination file.");
        fclose(source); // Close the source file before exiting.
        return 1;
    }

    while (fgets(buffer, sizeof(buffer), source)) {
        char *p = buffer;
        int blank_space = 1;
        while(*p != '\0') {
            if (!isspace((unsigned char) *p)) {
                blank_space = 0;
                break;
            }
            p++;
        }
        if(!blank_space) {
            fputs(buffer, destination);
        }
    }

    fclose(source);
    fclose(destination);

    return 0;   
}
```

Observed Behavior:

After entering the source file name and pressing enter, the program doesn't immediately prompt for the destination file name. It seems to wait until I press enter again.

Attempted Fixes:

- Used a space in the format string of scanf to ignore leading whitespace.
- Replaced scanf with fgets and manually removed the newline character.
- Explicitly flushed the stdin buffer after the first scanf.

OS: Windows 11

IDE: VS Code

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Are you sure this is the *exact* code you're compiling and running?

Comment: If the user types "`horrendously-long-name.out`" for the second file, you have a buffer overflow.  You should worry about the buffer sizes in `sscanf()`. See [How to prevent `scanf()` causing a buffer overflow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1621394/15168) — noting that the concepts apply to `sscanf()` et al as well as `scanf()` itself.

Comment: See also [Removing newline character from `fgets()` input?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/15168)

Comment: @dbush 
I have no clue how... I just played a game of CSGO, reran it after seeing your comment. Worked first try. Same exact code. Failed to run probably 60 times. What in the world?

Comment: `isspace()` takes an `int` so why do you cast it to an `unsigned char`?

Comment: `strlen(buffer) > 1` is an expensive way to write `*buffer` (or if you prefer `buffer[0] != '\0'`).

Comment: Why do you read stuff into buffer then into a variable?  Just read it into the variable and for the default output file name use a symbolic constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only issue I see with your code is the buffer overflow that @JonathanLeffler mentioned earlier.

If any line is longer than 1023 bytes then you may be deleting spaces in the middle of a very long line.  You should document this or even better generate an error if that assumption is invalidated (you can use the return value from `all()` to figure out if you got a long string; worst case you can't print the line till you see the last character of an arbitrary long line).

To improve readability I introduced `prompt_and_open()`.  This also reduces the scope of the file name to this function, and the bounce via `buffer` to remove the trailing newline.  It's also better UX to check if the source is available before prompting for the destination file name.  Readability was also the reason why I introduced the `all()` function.  Magic values are replaced by symbolic constants and it also addresses the potential buffer overflow.

Resource cleanup could be identical in the normal and error case but I prefer code duplication to carry a return value throughout `main()`  (i.e. `goto err` is better than `rv = 1; goto out;`).

```
#define _POSIX_C_SOURCE 200809L
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define BUFFER_LEN 1024
#define DESTINATION "output.txt"
#define DESTINATION_PROMPT "What would you like to name the duplicate file?"
#define NAME_LEN 256
#define SOURCE_PROMPT "Enter the source file name"

const char *all(const char *s, int (*f)(int)) {
    for(; *s; s++)
        if(!f(*s))
            return NULL;
    return s;
}

FILE *prompt_and_open(const char *prompt, const char *fallback, char *mode) {
    printf("%s", prompt);
    if(fallback)
        printf(" (default %s)", fallback);
    printf(": ");
    char name[NAME_LEN];
    fgets(name, NAME_LEN, stdin);
    name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';
    if(fallback && !*name)
        *stpncpy(name, fallback, NAME_LEN-1) = '\0';
    return fopen(name, mode);
}

int main(void) {
    FILE *source = NULL;
    FILE *destination = NULL; // simplifies error handling

    source = prompt_and_open(SOURCE_PROMPT, NULL, "r");
    if(!source) {
        perror("The source file was not found.");
        goto err;
    }
    destination = prompt_and_open(DESTINATION_PROMPT, DESTINATION, "w");
    if(!destination) {
        perror("Could not create the destination file.");
        goto err;
    }
    char buffer[BUFFER_LEN];
    while(fgets(buffer, sizeof buffer, source))
        if(!all(buffer, isspace))
            fputs(buffer, destination);
    fclose(source);
    fclose(destination);
    return 0;
err:
    if(source) fclose(source);
    if(destination) fclose(destination);
    return 1;
}
```